# Img displayed in binary code with correct header on browser

Tags: php, image, header, gd

I build a class of  imgResize:

```
class imgResize
{
   public static function resizeAndOutput($img) {

    $orginal_img = $img;
    $width = 591;
    $height = 332;
    $new_width = 161;
    $new_height = 91;

    $edit_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($orginal_img);
    imagecopyresampled($edit_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    imagejpeg($edit_img);
}
```

}

and in html I try to get this on the fly `img` displayed:

```
<img class="img_small" src="<?php imgResize::resizeAndOutput($img)">
```

just getting binary datas like this:

```
�����JFIF���������>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality ���C�           $.'
```

How can i solve my problem?

Comment: Where do you actually return the image source from the function? I can't see any return statements?

Comment: i dont need a return statement, coz i am creating a imagejpeg temporary

Comment: Ok if you don't want to save it, then you don't need the `img` element too.. The imagejpeg will show the image in the page... It's like you open an image directly with it's url.. Because In the php it is used that way : [imagejpeg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)

Comment: miro Markarian
it dont work like you say it displays binary too

Comment: Maybe you're outputting something to browser before the script. Like a html.. When using this method, you SHOULDN'T have any html in the file. Because as the browser see the html tags it will set the content type to another thing.. Your file sould start with `<?php` and end with `?>` and should only output once, that is the `imagejpeg` function. There should be no other output..

Comment: And I bet you're getting a `Headers Already Sent` warning too. But you have the `display_errors` off so you don't see it. Am I right?

Comment: ofc i do this the resizeAndOutput function dont output anything just the img if i save this file with a name it works

Comment: yes maybe i have some display_errors didnt see it :(
trying actually the base64 uri method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to encode your image in a data uri (and embedding the base64 encoded data as a string in your html) and removing that header() line in php,

or create a link to that image, for example http://example.com/?myimage=id and outputting the image as you are doing (as in giving correct headers and echoing the resulting image)

tell me if you need more info or this gives enough insights.

Comment: //header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($edit_img);
return base64_encode($edit_img);

and addet in src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <php? echo imgResize::resizeAndOutput($img) ?>"

Comment: could you write a example ? what should i do to get base64 working?

Comment: what you wrote in the comment should be correct, try to paste the resulting string in your browser (so something like data:image/jpeg;base64,asdkljasdklasd== ) and see what image you got.

Comment: ob_start ();
imagejpeg($edit_img);
$image_data = ob_get_contents ();
ob_end_clean (); 
return base64_encode($image_data); this worked thx DRC

Answer (score 0):

If you output it directly into a `src` element, it will of course just be binary garbage inside HTML. That's not how `<img>` elements work. An `<img>` element's `src` needs to have a **URL** pointing to the image. This can be either a URL like `img/foo.jpg`, or `app/some_script_that_outputs_an_image.php`, or a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Uri). But not simply binary data. The script that outputs the image would work in this second case, as target of a `app/some_script_that_outputs_an_image.php` link.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do it right but in the last part you have a problem. You have to save the image and then return the `url` of the image to the `img` element.. Try this code:

```
class imgResize
{
   public static function resizeAndOutput($img) {

    $orginal_img = $img;
    $width = 591;
    $height = 332;
    $new_width = 161;
    $new_height = 91;

    $edit_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($orginal_img);
    imagecopyresampled($edit_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    //Now we have the image lets create a random filename
    //Modify this to your needs
    $filename = "images/IMG_" . mt_rand(1000,9999) . ".jpg";
    //Random sometimes sucks.. Lets see if we already got a file with that name
    //And if exists, loop until we get a unique one
    while(file_exists($filename)) {
        $filename = "images/IMG_" . mt_rand(1000,9999) . ".jpg";
    }
    //Now let's save the file
    imagejpeg($edit_img, $filename);
    //And finally return the file url
    return $filename;
}
}
```

If you don't want to save it, you should output it directly to the browser. You don't need any `img` tags. That's because when using `imagejpeg` it's like you have directly opened an image file in the browser. (I don't know if I was clear or not. I'm just trying to describe what it really is)

So the php file will be same and you don't need any html. Just call the function. it will do what it is needed:

`imgResize::resizeAndOutput($img);`

Answer (score 0):

```
class imgResize
```

{
   public static function resizeAndOutput($img) {

```
$orginal_img = $img;
$width = 591;
$height = 332;
$new_width = 161;
$new_height = 91;

$edit_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($orginal_img);
imagecopyresampled($edit_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
ob_start ();
imagejpeg($edit_img);
$image_data = ob_get_contents ();
ob_end_clean ();
return base64_encode($image_data);
```

}

HTML

```
<img class="img_small" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo imgResize::resizeAndOutput($img)">
```

Comment: this works quite good for me hope i can help with this other guys hf